# What is necessary to use a phonegap plugin?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on a project where I need to use `navigator.notification.alert ...` as a replacement for `alert()` (because `alert()` has a label at the top saying `index.html`).

I am using the PhoneGap View application for iOS to test this application out, and nowhere does it allow me to invoke that method (`navigator.notification.alert()`).

Here is what I did:

- Installed the plugin using `phonegap plugin add ...`
- Called the method `... .alert(...)`

Since I am fairly new to Phonegap and Cordova, I would like a list of everything I would need to actually use this plugin.

Is there any JavaScript file which I would need to import? Is there a way to import the plugin into my HTML? Can I have a list of everything I need to do to use **any** PhoneGap plugin?

#### Update 1

Even after creating a new phonegap application, I don't get any cordova.js files:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding platform with (it will add cordova.js file which is necessary for plugins)

> `cordova platform add android/ios`

and then build

> `cordova build`

Possibly issue of Phonegap reported [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/issues/274) and [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/134).(Due to that its not adding `cordova.js` file)

> Do call any plugins after device ready because that makes plugins available. If you will call plugins directly then you may get plugins `undefined`.

For **Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Notification Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Empty
    }

    // alert dialog dismissed
    function alertDismissed() {
        // do something
    }

    // Show a custom alert
    //
    function showAlert() {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            alertDismissed,         // callback
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Done'                  // buttonName
        );
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Show Alert</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Reference](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html)

Regards.

Comment: Oops not `phonegap.js` but `cordova.js`

Answer (score 1):

Any phonegap plugin will work after `deviceready` event is fired. So make sure `deviceready` is fired before calling the `navigator.notification.alert()` method.

Since you are adding plugins through the `cli` no need to import any javascript file. You just add a reference to `cordova.js` file if not there in your html page.

Hope it helps you.

check the project below structure 
[image]

Comment: but there is no cordova.js file in my `www` directory

Comment: It should have cordova.js file otherwise any cordova libraries don't load in your project

Comment: In my **Update 1**, even Phonegap does not generate the cordova.js file for me. Is there anywhere online where I can access the file?

Comment: another question: will I have to use the 'deviceready' event listener for every page of my application?

Comment: I suggest you to install cordova. "npm install -g cordova" and create project by using cordova command finally add platform and plugin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118280/discussion-between-naresh-kumar-and-viraj-shah).